# What causes the error message "System running in low graphics mode" and how can I avoid it?

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I have tried twice to upgrade to 12.04 LTS and on both occasions get the above error message. I have read all the stuff on this and nothing works.

I have now tried a clean install from a downloaded disc and **everything is fine** but I am concerned about installing updates as clearly one of them will start the problem again.

Any suggestions as to what causes the problem and is there a likely update that should be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is a low memory work environment (When Ubuntu dosent have enough space to load everything.

What YOU can do:

1) Insert an ubuntu CD/DVD
2) Restart and use the BIOS (Basic Input/Output System)

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't think that was the problem.  I have now tried a clean install and only accepted security updates, and to date have had no further problem.